# Error message exec.go:282] constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

What can cause this error message when I upgrade the helm chart?

```
W0412 18:17:08.070731   11236 exec.go:282] constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; 1230 clients constructed calling "doctl"
```

So what are the clients and what particular part is responsible for constructing to many of them?

Comment: most probably its better to submit an issue on github

Comment: not clear is there an issue or just a correct warning

Comment: see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/91913